# Подчеркивание пункта меню с использованием js и jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Хочу сделать подчеркивание пункта меню на js,
чтобы полоска передвигалась под тот пункт меню, на который наведена мышка.
Вот мой код  http://jsfiddle.net/naXja/5/
Пункты меню разной ширины, не получается сделать так, чтобы полоска была той ширины, что и пункт меню и находилась под ним.
Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: вычисляйте положение элемента на который навели, а полосочке  сообщайте новые координаты, анимацию можно сделать как transition, так и jQuery .animation()

Comment: @eicto а можете объяснить подробнее, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

С небольшим костылем вышло [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bjKEJ/5/)

Comment: я ваш костыль немного переделал, а-то там был глюкс
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bjKEJ/5/

Comment: @eicto, спасибо :) Оформьте как ответ. у меня костілестроение закончилось с инлексом 4, провтікал обновить в ответе

Comment: 4й индекс тоже мой, ваш 3й, просто себе заберите с объяснением :) код же ваш :)